# Hide DIV until its items are wrapped in its default height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I do not know my question title is good enough or not, let me explain here

On http://www.wholesalerhinestones.org/ there is a DIV with class `sj-responsive-listing`

When site is loaded, products inside that DIV are all over the place on the site and after a second those are wrapped inside a specified `hight`

I want to do is that Hide that DIV until all products are wrapped inside that DIV to a specified height.

I have tried

```
.sj-responsive-listing{
display:none;
}
```

And then

```
    $('.sj-responsive-listing').load(function() {
        // When the page has loaded
        $('.sj-responsive-listing').show();
    });
```

immediately inside that SCRIPT that after the DIV with `sj-responsive-listing` class but it does not work. The DIV does not even show.

I also tried only

```
  $('.sj-responsive-listing').show();
```

But again all products are shown and after some time are wrapped inside height

**The things I tried are not on**

Answer (score 2):

[**.load**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) doesn't do what you think it does.

Try [**.ready**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  $('.sj-responsive-listing').show();
});
```

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
         $('.sj-responsive-listing').show();
        ;
        (function(element) {
            var $respl = $(element);
            var $container = $('.respl-items', $respl);

Answer (score 1):

Check [waitforimages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) and [imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)

You can do for example:

```
$('.mydiv').waitForImages(function(){
  $(this).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the fixed height to that div and give css `overflow: hidden` to same div so it dosn't show the extra items.

Comment: Please notice there is LOAD MORE button. So when that button is clicked more items are loaded and DIV's height is increased